# HTML - Float 3 tables next to each other but have text below

Tags: html, css

I am floating 3 tables next to each other using `<table style="float:left;">` and this works just fine.  However, I have some text that I want at the very bottom, and I want it to be left justified.  Currently, it is just being wrapped to the right side of the right-most table.  I've confirmed that it is outside of all of my tables.  My html is below.  This creates 3 tables, with nested tables within them.  The 3 main tables line up next to each other, but I want the text to be at the bottom and not shoved off to the left...

```css
td,
th {
  font-family: calibri;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.tablestyle {
  font-family: calibri;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 420px;
}

.wide {
  width: 40%;
}

.thin {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Weather Summary for <u>$date</u>:</h2><br>

<table style="float:left;">
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Temperature</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hTemp</td>
      <td>$aTemp</td>
      <td>$lTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dewpoint (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hDewPnt</td>
      <td>$aDewPnt</td>
      <td>$lDewPnt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Humidity (%)</td>
      <td>$hHum</td>
      <td>$aHum</td>
      <td>$lHum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Feels Like (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hFeels</td>
      <td>$aFeels</td>
      <td>$lFeels</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apparent Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hAppTemp</td>
      <td>$aAppTemp</td>
      <td>$lAppTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Heat Index (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hHeatInd</td>
      <td>$aHeatInd</td>
      <td>$lHeatInd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Chill (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hWndChl</td>
      <td>$aWndChl</td>
      <td>$lWndChl</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Wind & Pressure</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure (inHg)</td>
      <td>$mxPress</td>
      <td>$aPress</td>
      <td>$mnPress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Speed (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWind</td>
      <td>$aWind</td>
      <td>$lWind</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Gust (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWndGst</td>
      <td>$aWndGst</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Direction</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$aWndDir</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Rain & Evaporation</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Total</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rainfall (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$totRain</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rain Rate (in/Hr)</td>
      <td>$rainRate</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evapotranspiration (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$evapoTrans</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Solar</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UV Index</td>
      <td>$hUV</td>
      <td>$aUV</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solar Radiation (W/m&sup2;)</td>
      <td>$hSolRad</td>
      <td>$aSolRad</td>
      <td>-</td</tr>
  </table>
</table>
<table style="float:left;">
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Temperature</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hTemp</td>
      <td>$aTemp</td>
      <td>$lTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dewpoint (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hDewPnt</td>
      <td>$aDewPnt</td>
      <td>$lDewPnt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Humidity (%)</td>
      <td>$hHum</td>
      <td>$aHum</td>
      <td>$lHum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Feels Like (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hFeels</td>
      <td>$aFeels</td>
      <td>$lFeels</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apparent Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hAppTemp</td>
      <td>$aAppTemp</td>
      <td>$lAppTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Heat Index (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hHeatInd</td>
      <td>$aHeatInd</td>
      <td>$lHeatInd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Chill (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hWndChl</td>
      <td>$aWndChl</td>
      <td>$lWndChl</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Wind & Pressure</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure (inHg)</td>
      <td>$mxPress</td>
      <td>$aPress</td>
      <td>$mnPress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Speed (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWind</td>
      <td>$aWind</td>
      <td>$lWind</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Gust (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWndGst</td>
      <td>$aWndGst</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Direction</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$aWndDir</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Rain & Evaporation</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Total</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rainfall (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$totRain</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rain Rate (in/Hr)</td>
      <td>$rainRate</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evapotranspiration (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$evapoTrans</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Solar</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UV Index</td>
      <td>$hUV</td>
      <td>$aUV</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solar Radiation (W/m&sup2;)</td>
      <td>$hSolRad</td>
      <td>$aSolRad</td>
      <td>-</td</tr>
  </table>
</table>
<table style="float:left;">
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Temperature</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hTemp</td>
      <td>$aTemp</td>
      <td>$lTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dewpoint (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hDewPnt</td>
      <td>$aDewPnt</td>
      <td>$lDewPnt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Humidity (%)</td>
      <td>$hHum</td>
      <td>$aHum</td>
      <td>$lHum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Feels Like (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hFeels</td>
      <td>$aFeels</td>
      <td>$lFeels</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apparent Temperature (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hAppTemp</td>
      <td>$aAppTemp</td>
      <td>$lAppTemp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Heat Index (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hHeatInd</td>
      <td>$aHeatInd</td>
      <td>$lHeatInd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Chill (&#8457;)</td>
      <td>$hWndChl</td>
      <td>$aWndChl</td>
      <td>$lWndChl</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Wind & Pressure</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure (inHg)</td>
      <td>$mxPress</td>
      <td>$aPress</td>
      <td>$mnPress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Speed (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWind</td>
      <td>$aWind</td>
      <td>$lWind</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Gust (mph)</td>
      <td>$hWndGst</td>
      <td>$aWndGst</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wind Direction</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$aWndDir</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Rain & Evaporation</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Total</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rainfall (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$totRain</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rain Rate (in/Hr)</td>
      <td>$rainRate</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evapotranspiration (in)</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>$evapoTrans</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <th colspan="4">Solar</th>
    <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <th col span="1" class="thin"></th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Maximum</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Average</th>
      <th col span="1" class="thin">Minimum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UV Index</td>
      <td>$hUV</td>
      <td>$aUV</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solar Radiation (W/m&sup2;)</td>
      <td>$hSolRad</td>
      <td>$aSolRad</td>
      <td>-</td</tr>
  </table>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<b>Definitions:</b><br>
<br>
<u>Feels Like</u>: attempts to quantify what human skin detects as the temperature, taking into account any warming or cooling effect of exposure to different humidity levels, high wind, or shade/sunshine.<br>
<u>Apparent Temperature</u>: the general term for the perceived outdoor temperature, caused by the combined effects of air temperature, relative humidity and wind speed.<br>
<u>Heat Index</u>: an index that combines air temperature and relative humidity in an attempt to determine the human-perceived equivalent temperature - how hot it feels.<br>
<u>Wind Chill</u>: takes into account how the speed of the wind affects our perception of the air temperature. The faster the wind blows, the faster heat from our bodies is carried away and the colder the environment feels.<br>
<u>Evapotranspiration</u>: the process by which water is transferred from the land to the atmosphere by evaporation from the soil and other surfaces and by transpiration from plants.<br>
<u>UV Index</u>: a measure of the intensity of ultraviolet radiation from the sun at the sun's highest point on a particular day in a particular place.<br>
<u>Solar Radiaton</u>: energy radiated from the sun in the form of electromagnetic waves, including visible and ultraviolet light and infrared radiation.<br>
```

Comment: You have already been answered, but so that you understand what the matter is, I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the concept [float and clear](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything after the tables in a div and

```
<div style="clear: both;">
```